# Handling Complex, Multi-Layer Form Data in React - Checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, use-reducer

I'm using the React hook useReducer to handle complex, multi-layer form data in state.

I have followed the direction from this tutorial: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/handling-complex-form-state-using-react-hooks-76ee7bc937.

In the tutorial, the checkbox state is set at the top level of the state object. However, My checkbox is below the top layer (layer 3 to be exact). The problem is that my checkbox component will change it's state value, but will place itself at the top level and not where it's supposed to be at level 3.

**Tutorial's State**
*isMember* is at the top level

```
const initialState = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  address: {
    addressLine1: "",
    addressLine2: "",
    pinCode: ""
  },
  isMember: false
};
```

**My State**
*enabled* is below the top level

```
const initState = 
{
  radio:{
    tx: {
      name:'',
      enabled:'',//THIS IS WHERE THE STATE SHOULD CHANGE.
      parameters:{
        frequency:'',
        bandwidth:'', 
      },
    },
  }
  //BUT THIS IS WHERE IT IS GETTING SET.
};
```

Below is my implementation of the updateForm function:

```
const updateForm = React.useCallback(({ target: { value, name, type } }) => {
    const updatePath = name.split(".");
    console.log("updateForm | updatePath: ", updatePath);

    // Set top-level key-pairs.
    // Just need specific component & value to update.
    if (updatePath.length === 1) {
      const [id] = updatePath;

      dispatch({
        type: "TF",
        [id]: value
      });
    }

    // Set key-pairs that're below top-level.
    // Need "path" to component ('name') & value to update.
    // More condensed solution, rather than multiple if(length === 3,4,...).
    if (updatePath.length >= 2) {
      // Set checkboxes.
      if (type === "checkbox") {
        let elem = updatePath[updatePath.length - 1];

        dispatch(prevState => ({
          [name]: !prevState[name]
        }));
        return;
      }

      dispatch({
        _path: updatePath,
        _value: value
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

I have tried many different approaches to the dispatch function and the reducer function. I have also tried understanding the relationship between the dispatch and reducer functions, but I haven't found anything that helps me understand what's happening when the reducer's action parameter is of type function.

I could really use your help understanding what's going on with the checkbox dispatch/reducer function relationship in the tutorial. From what I've researched, this is the only implementation that uses the reducer's action parameter's constructor type to make decisions (using constructor === Function & constructor === Object). From what I understand, typically a switch() statement is used instead, and that's all I've been able to find online.

I could also use your help understanding how to get my checkbox to correctly change its value in state. Basically, how do I change the state of this component that is below the top layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continuing to try out more ideas, I came to a solution I can live with. Hopefully this solution will help anyone who experiences the same problem.

I changed the checkbox section in my *updateForm()* as follows:

*updateForm()*

```
// Set checkboxes.
      if (type === "checkbox"){
        dispatch({
          _path: updatePath,
          _value: checked,
          _type: type
        });
        return;
      }
```

In the *reducer()* method I completely avoid checking for constructor of type Function, and implement checkbox data handling as follows:

*reducer()*

```
if(has(updateArg, "_path") && has(updateArg, "_value") && has(updateArg, "_type")){
      const { _path, _value, _type } = updateArg;

      if(_type === "checkbox"){
        return produce(state, draft => {
          set(draft, _path, _value)
        })
      }
    }
```

I don't especially like this solution due reliance on the checkbox's *checked* element property. The tutorial's implementation of using the *prevState* argument would be my preference, but obviously I wasn't able to get it to work in my circumstance.

If anyone comes up with a better solution I will mark that as the answer. I would appreciate any thoughts and opinions as well.